# Populate Data in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I already did a lot of searching and become more and more confuse on the my requirement. Took me about 2 days to find the solution. let me explain what is my requirement

basically i have one table

```
  ----------------------------
 | Id |   DateLog  |  TimeLog |
 |----|------------|----------|
 | 01 | 2014-06-20 | 15:15:05 |
 | 01 | 2014-06-20 | 17:43:21 |
 | 02 | 2014-06-20 | 19:12:10 |
 | 02 | 2014-06-20 | 13:11:00 |
```

and i want to populate that above table to be similar like this

```
  ---------------------------------------
 | Id |   DateLog  |  TimeIn  |  TimeOut |
 |----|------------|----------|----------|
 | 01 | 2014-06-20 | 15:15:05 | 17:43:21 |
 | 02 | 2014-06-20 | 13:11:00 | 19:12:10 |
```

TimeIn column will be based on the earlyIn of the userId and TimeOut will be based on Last Out of the userId and group them by their Id.

i tried do something like this but the output its not like what i want.

```
select id,DateLog,
(
  select top 1 Timelog From dbo.[myAttendance]
  order by TimeLog Asc
)AS TimeIn,
(
  select top(1) TimeLog From dbo.[myAttendance]
  order by TimeLog Desc
)AS TimeOut
from dbo.[myAttendance]
group by Id
```

hopefully you guys can help me on this issue.

Comment: Please format your code and data using 4 spaces and line breaks, it's very difficult to read as is.  What exactly are you asking? You have two separate table definitions and a query, but what is the issue and expectation?

Comment: so each day each user will have one time in (min), and one time out (max), am i right ?

Comment: @hoangnnm yes..each day each user will have one time in and time out

Comment: @Kritner sorry for the messing...first time posting in stackoverview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, assuming Id is the User's ID  :

```
select id, datelog, min(timelog) as TimeIn, max(timelog) as TimeOut 
    from tablename 
    group by id, datelog
```